# Duplicating Data

Tags: sql

looking at duplicating data to include a type A and type B

```
select *
    from [dbo].[dayStats]
    where status in ('IDmon', 'IDtue', 'IDwed', 'IDthu', 'IDfri')
    order by status
```

currently have around 3000 records.

i need to duplicate each of these records so they include a A and B

for example:

```
IDmon
IDtue ...
```

becomes

```
IDmonA, IDmonB
IDtueA, IDtueB
...
```

no IDmon / IDtue records to remain

all the other fields are to be duplicated as normal

really struggling to think how i would create such a query / stored procedure

Comment: Which RDBMS? Which database are you using? Also based on what condition should the value be updated as A or B?

Comment: sql server 2008 r2, condition is just a straight duplication (per half of the status) e.g. there are 2 parts of a status(day) / 2 parts of IDmon so each record with status = IDmon will need to split into IDmonA and IDmon. with no IDmon record remaining..

Comment: sql server 2008 r2, condition is that the status must have a starttime(all records have a starttime). from there just a straight duplication is needed (per half of the status) e.g. there are 2 parts of IDmon so each record with status = IDmon will need to split into IDmonA and IDmon. with no IDmon record remaining..

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure if you're after this?

```
select
  status & 'A',
  status & 'B',
  other_col_1,
  other_col_2
from
  [dbo].[dayStats]
where status in ('IDmon', 'IDtue', 'IDwed', 'IDthu', 'IDfri')
```